# Children's play with a blue alien named 'Zeeto'?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, theater-play

When I was a small child, I went to a play with a character who gave me nightmares for months.

- Presumably a children's play.
- Performance was in the early 80s.
- Performance was probably in the Toronto area.
- The character what portrayed with indigo/dark blue skin.
- The character's name was 'Zeeto' or something similar.
- I don't believe the character or play were intended to be scary.
- I believe Zeeto was the only alien in the play and probably interacted with human kids?
- I think Zeeto was played by a man and his face was rendered with paint or a tight-fitting mask, not, for example with an oversized plushy costume and definitely not a puppet.
- I have a vague impression the theatre was large (but keep in mind I was small) and I'm pretty sure I was seated in a balcony.

Can anyone identify the play?

---

Somehow I ended up back here and did a little more digging.  At least the idea that it could be at the [Young People's Theatre](https://www.youngpeoplestheatre.org/) came into my mind as a likely destination for a school field trip.  Here's a listing of [all their shows](https://www.youngpeoplestheatre.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/ALL-SEASONS-updated-Summer-2022.pdf).  1980-1 *Invasion from the Polar Planet* looked interesting but I can't find any more information on it, and it's probably too early.  It may also be that [The Canadian Theatre Encyclopedia](https://www.canadiantheatre.com/dict.pl) is of some use.

Comment: A green-skinned alien named Zeeto is a character in Korean elementary school curriculum. If you poke around ESL instructor pages, you'll see that many teachers are sick of him. :) The Scroungers Trilogy has an alien named Zeeto (or maybe Zeefo), but that's a novel.

Comment: @SeanDuggan:   Interesting, but probably not it.

Comment: I keep flashing to Teller's character in Babylon 5, but that can't be it.

Comment: As a service to future answerers, this was not one of the public service plays / skits involving the blue aliens Binkley and Doinkel that used to happen in the Toronto area in that time period.

Comment: @Praxis.  You should put the answer back.  Although incorrect,  I was going to give you an upvote just because I was impressed!

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Done --- thanks!

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I have to ask, just to be certain: you're not thinking of Flotter and Naomi Wildman from *Voyager*, are you?  :-)

Comment: @Praxis:   Ha!   No, that is way too late!   But you did give me flashbacks when I pulled up the image of Flotter.

Comment: @Praxis:  care to pick up the trail?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Intriguing.  I’ll see if I can rustle up the old magic and produce a (correct) answer.

Comment: @Praxis:   :) Just like old times :)

Answer (score 10):

## Binkley and Doinkel

Binkley and Doinkel were blue aliens who used to spread public service messages in the late 1970s and early 1980s in Canadian cities, including the Greater Toronto Area.  They appeared in advertisements and, on occasion, in person in safety "skits".

[image]

I'm not sure about "Zeeto", but it could have been the name of one of the many anti-safety "villains" they were pitted against.

Comment: Sorry man,  but no dice.   The Praxman can be stumped!  No dog.  And just the one alien.  I'm certain his name wasn't Blinkey or Doinkel.

Comment: Totally incorrect,  but take an upvote because I'm impressed.

Comment: I'm giving you this +100 bounty only because the rep will vanish otherwise.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Thanks.  I'll do right by it, by continuing to work on this...  :-)

Answer (score 7):

## Live taping / performance of *Read All About It!*

*Read All About It!* was a children's television series produced by TVO (Television Ontario) and filmed in Brampton in the Greater Toronto Area.  It aired from 1979-1983. The principal antagonist was an alien named **Doneedon**, played by a man whose face was painted a blueish-silver. TVO described the show as a **"dynamic serial with a science fiction format..."**

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212687/):

> When three kids explore a coach house held by a missing uncle, they discover far more than they bargained for when two robots, Otto and Theta, appear to tell them about a conspiracy against the town. By accident, they also discover a teleport machine that can take them to the planet Trialveron controlled by the alien tyrant, Duneedon. Against this threat, the kids decide to use the coach-house as the base for a community newspaper both to keep the building and to investigate the conspiracy. Along the way, they learn about writing and its various practical uses as they fight the alien forces that oppose them.

Although intended for children, many viewers found the show to be quite frightening at the time.

At the height of its popularity around 1982 and 1983, there were ***live tapings of the show and one or two special live performances in the Toronto area.***  It also spawned a few novels.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I totally remember this show.   I can remember its theme song.   There was an episode where the bad guy messing with the robotic typewriter (see the picture) and the kids get back to the base and it (he?) types something like *Teh badw guy wis here!*  which they interpret as *Badguy was here*, but then they realize it meant **is here** dun-dun-*DUN*.

Comment: But, by the way, it's wrong.   Sorry :(    Still, have an upvote for effort.